# Remove a space before an argument, while adding '(' and ')' with VIM surround

Tags: vim, surround

using vim with the plugin [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) pretty extensively, and I am really happy with it. However, there is one replacement for witch I haven't found a nice shortcut.

The usage case, is the following. I need :

```
def function argument
```

to become (when the cursor is in the middle of the 'argument')

```
def function(argument)
```

My attempts didn't completely fulfil my need:

I have try

```
ysiw) => def function (argument) # I don't like the space after the function
ysaw) => def function( argument) # I don't like the space before the argument
```

Since, there is always a shortcut with vim, I am asking the communitity to help me satisfy my style obsession...

Comment: I don't have vim-surround available, but the quickest I can think of would be `F xysw)` *assuming* surround can take just a motion and not only text-objects.  This isn't very short or creative though.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: When does that use case come up? I don't remember ever having to make such a change ...

Comment: Surround leaves you on the starting parenthesis. It is very little effort to do  `lx` or `hx` to remove the space. However if you do end up doing this kind of operation often then you may want to think about recording a macro or setting up a custom mapping.

Comment: @gits : ruby accepts both syntax for passing a parameter to method. However, I definitely prefer the one with parenthesis since it is (in my opinion) more clear and it can be allow to chain method.

Comment: @RandyMorris it works ! Creative or not, I'll find a shortcut for that... Thanks for your help

Comment: @PeterRincker, yes, I'll end up doing a custom mapping for this.

Answer (score 1):

Without vim on hand, I think that

```
nmap <F6> F xyse)
```

or

```
nmap <F6> ysiw)F x
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This command works, but for a mysterious reason, the mapping doesn't work as expected. It seems to me that surround command (ys) cannot be added like this in a mapping...

Comment: `ys` is not a native command as it is provided by surround.vim. You will have to use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`